# Why do i need bios emulation?

Tags: partition, bios, emulation

I asked the question why i have a 100mb partition and its apparently for bios emulation
[Additional partition being created when installing Windows 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/35952/partition-and-windows-7)

My mac intel has that partition, this laptop i deleted that partition and found a 8mb partition instead. My question is, why do i need that bios emulation? This comp seems to run fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

See http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/UEFIrequirements.docx for some Microsoft info on EFI and how Windows uses it. This article is a bit technical. Wikipedia have a more accessible, though more general, article on EFI at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface.

JR